# Alternative for fs.readFile when targeting the web using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webpack, fs

In my Electron application I am reading some application files (not user files, but actual files in the Electron application root) using `fs.readFile` however this obviously won't work when packing for the web. Alternatively I tried to implement something along the lines of the following:

```
function loadFile(filePath: string) {
    let result = null;
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        result = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following exception: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///[...]/Testfile.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`

I'd like to know which approach I can use to load the content of a "server" file and not local file (even though I am testing locally at the moment) when packing for the web.

Comment: Have you looked into using a webpack loader for the particular file type you are trying to package? For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-loader

Comment: @Mark_M I do not intend to pack the contents of the text file (for example) into the webpack bundle and want to be able to dynamically load requested files that come with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution did not work as I have opened the application locally in my browser and thus the request protocol was `file://`. In order to be able to debug it I installed [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) and started a local server to test the app.

Answer (score -1):

Have your questions been answered?
If not. try this:

```
if (xmlhttp.status === 200 || xmlhttp.status === 0) {
    result = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```